# What is the destination of the used tennis balls from tournaments?

Tags: equipment, tennis, tournaments

During the tennis tournaments, every 7 games the balls [are changed](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4757/how-many-balls-on-tennis-ground).

What is the destination of those used balls? I think there were a lot of balls every tournaments of that

Comment: See my answer on this similar question.
http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4759/18

Comment: They are recycled mostly. And you could find great tips for your good ol' yellow ball : http://www.atpworldtour.com/news/deuce-tennis/deuce-australian-open-2009/old-tennis-balls.aspx

Comment: Here is version of the article linked by Nicolas Charvoz [from Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20150320224048/http://www.atpworldtour.com/News/DEUCE-Tennis/DEUCE-Australian-Open-2009/Old-Tennis-Balls.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Wimbledon for example, they sell the balls! Not sure about other tournaments but I assume they do likewise.

[Source:](http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/about_aeltc/201205091336574376496.html)

> Balls
>
> 54,250 used during The Championships period.  Stored at 68 deg F.  New balls after first seven games (to allow for warm-up), then after every 9 games. Subject to availability after use balls sold daily to LTA-affiliated clubs and to spectators in the grounds.  £2.50 per can of three.  Proceeds go to LTA's Wimbledon Balls for Schools Scheme.  Yellow balls used for first time in 1986.  At start of day 48 tins taken onto Centre and No.1 Courts and 24 on all outside courts.